# Change entire row to nan if condition in 3 columns met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 400 columns of frequency data and 3 columns with whether pumps 1 -> 3 are "RUNNING" or "STOPPED".

I want to change entire rows to nan where a condition on pump is met. (It doesn't matter if this changes the pump rows as I drop those columns after this)

For example I've tried

```
df[(df["Pump Set 1"] != "STOPPED") & (df["Pump Set 2"] != "STOPPED") & (df["Pump Set 3"] != "STOPPED")] = None
```

When I do this and print df.head(), I see no change but if I try and to

```
df = df[etc
```

I get a none type error.
All other examples I've seen online require specifying the columns to change and I don't want to specify 400 columns.

Comment: This `df[(df["Pump Set 1"] != "STOPPED") & (df["Pump Set 2"] != "STOPPED") & (df["Pump Set 3"] != "STOPPED")] ` is sufficient for you to keep only wanted rows.

Comment: Ok so how do I keep all values and change those to nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for all columns:

```
mask = (df["Pump Set 1"] != "STOPPED") & 
       (df["Pump Set 2"] != "STOPPED") & 
       (df["Pump Set 3"] != "STOPPED")
df.loc[mask, :] = None
```

Or pass all columns:

```
df.loc[mask, df.columns] = None
```

Comment: It runs without error but the output is the unchanged dataframe, note it works with just one condition seems to not work with all three

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd - one idea, if check `print (mask)` are `Trues` where it is expected?

Comment: The masking works as intended it seems but the & does not seem to working as exclusive and. It seems to be functioning as an or function basically. 
Oh I need to use a different operator

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd - I ask because maybe if check separately there should be some traling whitesapce like `STOPPED `. So if check `print ((df["Pump Set 1"] != "STOPPED"))`, `print ((df["Pump Set 2"] != "STOPPED"))` and `print ((df["Pump Set 3"] != "STOPPED"))` then is possible verify if all working like expected

Comment: For posterity, I changed the != to == so that it would find all rows where exclusively all pumps were off (what I wanted to keep) and then inverted that mask in the df.loc statement -> df.loc[~mask, df.columns].